# Can we add to the FAQ something about Fritzing vs schematic diagrams?

Tags: feature-request

The topic of whether Fritzing diagrams are acceptable/liked/allowed has been discussed ([What do we think of Fritzing?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1221/2028)) as has a request for more information about posting normal schematics ([FAQ about posting schematics](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1076/2028)).

1. When a user posts a Fritzing diagram, is it possible to detect this and show some information about what a schematic diagram is versus a Fritzing diagram? This would not prohibit Fritzing links of course, but just provide a cautionary notification.
2. Failing that, I think a *visual* comparison of the two would be a good addition to the FAQ, so that we can point new or inexperienced users to it.

I agree with Olin and Clabacchio in the first question I linked, in that a Fritzing is better than nothing (it at least shows that the user is trying to share pertinent technical information). However, I find that comments on questions with such diagrams are often not overly helpful for the OP. For example: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/103604/2028

Comment: There's really no excuse for not providing a schematic in addition to (or instead of) the breadboard diagram, since the Fritzing software maintains both representations in parallel anyway.

Comment: @Dave I agree, but I wonder if some users think the wiring diagram is better because they don't themselves know how to read a schematic?

Comment: Perhaps that's the point that any changes to the FAQ need to address.

Comment: You say the comments to the question you linked to in your last sentence weren't useful.  I just looked again, and the OP was told quite clearly what to do.  He refused to, so the question was closed.  If he had provided a schematic and the descriptions of what he wanted it to do and what it actually did, I think he would have gotten useful answers.  He may have originally thought the diagram was sufficient, but he was told clearly it wasn't.  If he had asked how to make the software dump out a schematic, people probably would have helped him with that.

Comment: @Olin I am one of the up-votes on your first comment at the linked question. I'm not saying it wasn't *useful*, just that it wasn't *overly helpful*. That question is really not a great example of educating a user about Fritzing vs. Schematics, but it reminded me to ask about it. The point is, it would be more helpful if we could direct users to some portion of the FAQ that *showed* them what a schematic looks like compared to whatever else they post, and it thus serves as a template as well as educational material.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to detect Fritzing diagrams, but I highly doubt anything like it could be integrated into the site.

Comment: @ChrisLaplante: why not? If it can be done for CircuitLab, why not Fritzing?

Comment: @flup: Because the goal is to *detect* Fritzing diagrams, not integrate an editor into the site.

Comment: @ChrisLaplante: OK, I was a bit confused by your using "integrated". My apologies

Comment: Complaints about fritzing is nothing but elitism. "how date you use a program that you are comfortable with instead of x or y that I'm familiar with". Instead of ignoring those questions, some people rather bully.

Comment: @Passerby Fritzing can produce a schematic as Dave mentioned. There's nothing elitist about it, it's simply about clear communication using standardized methods. Furthermore, the whole point of my proposal is to help users out, not ignore nor bully.

Comment: I always recommend people redraw a schematic instead of a Fritzing diagram because I find them time consuming and hard to decipher, especially when wires are at weird angles and just look messy. I'd say the same thing about a sloppily drawn schematic. Not elitist. I mean, there's a reason we don't share designs by taking a picture of our breadboards, right?

Answer (score 2):

I posted a question and answer pair that hopefully can be used as a basic reference for new users to help explain the merits and differences between schematics, wiring diagrams and other related things.

Perhaps linking to it will be sufficient for cases where a user posts an unclear image and needs a pointer.

- [What's a schematic (compared to other diagrams)?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/105136/2028)